# Как заменить "x" между цифрами в фразе на пробел

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как заменить "x" (или любой одиночный символ) между цифрами в фразе на пробел

Лотки неперфорированные 100х100х3000
Лотки неперфорированные 100х50х3000 дкс
Диски x-drive 205x55R16

пробовал разбить фразу на цифры и слова таким образом, но х от цифры отделить никак не получилось

```
preg_split('/(?<=[0-9])(?=[a-zA-Zа-яА-я])/i',$str);
```

Comment: `preg_replace('/([0-9])[^0-9]([0-9])/i', '\1 \2', 'Лотки неперфорированные 100x100x3000 Лотки неперфорированные 100x50x3000 дкс Диски x-drive 205x55R16', -1, $count);`

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться выражением, которое ищет "не цифру" между цифрами при помощи Positive Lookbehind и Lookahead

```
(?<=\d)\D(?=\d)
```

с помощью preg_replace

```
$re = '/(?<=\d)\D(?=\d)/u';
$subst = ' ';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: \D не воспринимает кириллицу

Comment: Достаточно модификатор `u` добавить http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a362aa3c93473536b9d91936d29a1fa71c657c6f

Answer (score 0):

preg_replace заменяет паттерн на новую строку. при чем можно использовать запись вида $1 для указания элементов в скобках из паттерна

```
<?php
$string = 'Лотки неперфорированные 100х100х3000 Лотки неперфорированные 100х50х3000 дкс Диски x-drive 205x55R16';

$pattern = '/(\d)\D(\d)/u'; //модификатор u что бы регулярка воспринимала кириллицу
$replace = '$1 $2';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $string);

//выводит
//Лотки неперфорированные 100 100 3000 Лотки неперфорированные 100 50 3000 дкс Диски x-drive 205x55R16
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, помогло